# Conversion of series to Dataframe Issue

Tags: python, pandas

After using groupby on a Dataframe to group and sum column data into a series I then converted the result back to a Dataframe using .to_frame method which I then converted to html for output to a file. This appears to work well except that the header row has a zero in the last column which I am unable to delete - any ideas? - see here 
0
Board Type NE Type Hardware Version Software Version

---

enter code here:

```
   NE_3 = NE_2.groupby(NE_2.columns.tolist(), as_index=False).size()
   NE_3 = NE_3.to_frame()

   NE_2 = NE_2.drop_duplicates()
   NE_3 = NE_3.drop(columns='NE Type') # This doesn't work due to the '0' corrupting the header row
   html_txt = NE_3.to_html()
   tfile.write(html_txt)
   tfile.write('<br/>')
```

Comment: What should `enter code here` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try - `NE_2 = NE_2.drop([0], axis=1)` if the name of last column is `0`.

In case, the name of the last column is `Version0`, you could try this -

```
cols = NE_2.columns
cols = cols[:-1] + cols[-1].replace('0','')
NE_2.columns = cols
```

Comment: Thanks the try option works but removes the entire column which has the totals for each of the entries

Comment: Thanks the try option works but removes the entire column which has the totals for each of the entries. The '0' is in the first row, last column followed by the actual header row. Ideally I need to remove the top row with the '0' but have not been able to find how

Comment: Ohh, sorry, I did not understand the issue. Try - `NE_2=NE_2.loc[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to write the Dataframe back as a csv file and then re-read it - this resolves the displacement in the header row. The '0' column can then be simply renamed -

NE_3 = NE_3.rename(columns={'0':'Total'})